# Detecting Text in an image

Tags: c#, aforge

I am using AForge.NET library for image processing. Using this library I am able detect basic shapes within an image. How can I detect the text within an image using the AForge.NET library?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [Optical Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) (OCR). One link I found on using it with AForge can be visited [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11285/Neural-Network-OCR). Some code from the link:

```
// "K" letter, but a little bit noised
float[] pattern = new float [] {
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.3f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f};

// get network's output
float[] output = neuralNet.Compute(pattern);

int i, n, maxIndex = 0;

// find the maximum from output
float max = output[0];
for (i = 1, n = output.Length; i < n; i++)
{
    if (output[i] > max)
    {
        max = output1[i];
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}

//
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
  "network thinks it is - " + (char)((int) 'A' + maxIndex));
```

The only other way I can think of doing it, is using [Tessaract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) which can read a wide variety of image formats and convert them to text in over 40 languages. There are also many other ways of doing it out there, including [using Microsoft Office](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41709/How-To-Use-Office-2007-OCR-Using-C), or [Emgu cv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/License_Plate_Recognition_in_CSharp).

There's one more link which might work. It detects playing cards in AForge, and while doing so reads the numbers or J, Q, and K in the corner. [You may have seen it already](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265354/Playing-Card-Recognition-Using-AForge-Net-Framewor).

Comment: @h3n that's too bad! You can view a short snippet someone posted [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Forging-Player-Card-Detection-and-Recognition-program-with-AForgeNet). There's a video in that link which is private, but might be [this video](http://tune.pk/video/2546933/playing-card-recognition-using-aforgenet).

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Microsoft Cognitive Services - Computer Vision API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api)

Optical Character Recognition (OCR) detects text in an image and extracts
 the recognized words into a machine-readable character stream